# Prolog pattern match and return

Tags: list, prolog, pattern-matching

New to Prolog here and already found it hard.

And here's the question: let's say I got a char list such as [h,e,l,l,o] and a unicode number 108(which is the letter "l").

I'm trying to write a function that take the elements of the list one by one and pattern match with the given unicode number. Once matched, return the reste of the list.

Worked on it for a whole day now , almost tried everything I can think of and I still didn't figure out how to make it work. Anyone got some ideas?

Comment: Please show your attempts and explain where you are stuck. Can Google: https://www.google.com/search?q=prolog+head+tail+iterate+list

Comment: first of all, what should the signature of the predicate be? e.g. name/arity and what each argument means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function([C|Chars], CutoffCode, Chars) :-
    char_code(C, CutoffCode).

function([C|Chars], CutoffCode, Result) :-
    not(char_code(C, CutoffCode)),
    function(Chars, CutoffCode, Result).
```

e.g.

```
?- function([h,e,l,l,o], 108, Result).
Result = [l, o]

?- function([h,e,l,l,o], 109, Result).
false
```

Comment: You certainly know better than to name a fun..., erm I mean *predicate*, "function" -:)

Comment: Thanks alot bro, I just miss the point that I can change the 'Tail/Chars' variable in the second predicat to make it more adaptive. You just give me a nice inspiration.

Comment: @brebs well they did say "*I'm trying to write a function*" 